# How to subtract elements from a vector in R?

Tags: r

For example, there are two vectors:
`A <- c('H','H','H','M','M','M','L')`
`B <- c('H','M','L')`
I would like to subtract B from A, which will produce a new vector like this:`C <- c('H','H','M','M')`
I've tried using match(), but it only returned the first index of vector A. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

we can use `pmatch`

```
 A[-pmatch(B,A)]
 [1] "H" "H" "M" "M"
```

or we could do:

```
as.character(do.call(rep,unname(data.frame(table(A)-table(B)))))
[1] "H" "H" "M" "M"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
data.table(A)[, grp := rowid(rleid(A))][!data.table(B)[,
     grp := rowid(rleid(B))], on = .(grp)]$A
#[1] "H" "H" "M" "M"
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems it doesn't work for me. My output was ```character(0)``` after trying your method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
rep(names(table(A)), pmax(0, (table(A) - table(B))))

[1] "H" "H" "M" "M"
```